# How to get softKeyboard up on focus method in Android :PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I am having one Html Page inside which I am having one textarea with id="txtMessage", Now on DOM ready method, I have put 
`$("#txtMessage").focus();`
but the issue is when the page gets load, I do get the cursor on textarea, but keyboard doesn't showed up. But if again I tap on the textarea field, keyboard appears.
Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's know. You can work around this in android by writeing native java code as plugin to programaticaly show softkeyboard.  [**Here are few hints**](http://www.x-services.nl/control-soft-keyboard-on-android-2-2-device-in-phonegap-cordova-application/311)